# Combine mysql count(*) for two different tables same column

Tags: mysql, select, count

I have two tables that store comments from two different users

```
Table1

id_table1 | comment | id_user | id_post

Table2

id_table2 | comment | id_someOtherUser | id_post
```

I would really like to make only one table out of this two because comments are posted on the same post, but i can't because i have two different id's for two different kind of users.

**My question is how can i list all posts DESC by number of comments combined from two tables?**

If i do something like

```
SELECT P.*, count(*) as count from Table1 AS T1
LEFT JOIN post AS P ON T1.id_post = P.id_post GROUP BY P.id_post ORDER BY count DESC
```

Then i have posts for table1, same can be done for table2, but how can i combine comments from both tables for the same post?

Comment: You can use `UNION`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `UNION ALL` to combine the two comment tables in a common format, then do the `JOIN`:

```
SELECT P.*, TC.count
FROM (
    SELECT Ts.id_post, count(*) AS count
    FROM (
          SELECT id_post FROM Table1
          UNION ALL
          SELECT id_post FROM Table2
    ) AS Ts
    GROUP BY Ts.id_post
) AS TC
LEFT JOIN post AS P ON TC.id_post = P.id_post
GROUP BY P.id_post
ORDER BY TC.count DESC
```

Comment: That's exactly what i was looking for, thanks! I have tried UNION ALL myself but it didn't workout since i was doing it with only one outer SELECT so i was missing id_post

Comment: Three `SELECT`s were undoubtedly overkill but I felt it would be easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to do separate counts on each table, then do a full outer join, and take the sum of each of the counts:

`SELECT id_post, (count1 + count2) AS total_count FROM 
(SELECT id_post, count(*) as count1 from Table1 AS T1
FULL OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT id_post, count(*) as count2 from Table2 AS T2)
USING(id_post))
ORDER BY total_count DESC`